# SUPER,REPLICATION CLIENT prev to external MySQL user

Tags: mysql, privileges, replication

I'm trying to create an MySQL slave, but I'm not able to grant `SUPER,REPLICATION CLIENT` to the external `powerdns` user.

I'm using phpMyAdmin and granted `ALL PRIVILEGES` to the `powerdns` user, but it still isn't working..

Command `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;` on external host/client (=powerdns user):

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the SUPER,REPLICATION CLIENT privilege for this operation
```

Command `SHOW GRANT;` on external host/client (=powerdns user):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for powerdns@xx.xx.xx.xxx                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'powerdns'@'xx.xx.xx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

What I'm doing wrong over here? I'm sure I'm logged to the correct users.

Comment: So you're saying that the remote user logs in, gets that response to `SHOW GRANTS;`, and then immediately can't run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`?

Comment: Fixed by copying ROOT..

Comment: Which "ROOT" are you talking about, and how did you "copy" it?

Comment: root user in phpmyadmin. "Copy user".

Answer (score 0):

Did you as changes to user are not noticed until you do this or login again?

```
flush privileges;
```